# Oracle cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables

Tags: database, oracle, clob

As per below, I want to create a record into another database remotely which will work when I changed c1 to some string in insert query but when I use c1 object it will through error as per the title.

Please note: it's working fine on same remote without @, and using c1 object, tried other solution but no avail, can someone help me with a script for this dbms_lob. And its remote to another remote db insert

```
set define off;
Declare 
c1 clob default ' ';
begin 

dbms_lob.append(c1,chr(10));dbms_lob.append(c1,q'[DOCTYPE]');

Insert into SYSTEM_CONFIG@rtfqa (CONFIG_ID,NAME,VALUE_OLD,TYPE,SUB_TYPE,FROM_SYSTEM,TO_SYSTEM,VALUE) values ((select max(config_id)+1 from SYSTEM_CONFIG@rtfqa),'CONTRACT_HASHTAG_EN',null,'system','system',null,null,c1);
end;
```

**ERROR**

```
Insert into SYSTEM_CONFIG@rtfqa (CONFIG_ID,NAME,VALUE_OLD,TYPE,SUB_TYPE,FROM_SYSTEM,TO_SYSTEM,VALUE) values ((select max(config_id)+1 from SYSTEM_CONFIG@rtfqa),'CONTRACT_HASHTAG_EN',null,'system','system',null,null,c1);
end;

>Error report -  
>ORA-06550: line 7, column 148:  
>PL/SQL: ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables  
>ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:  
>PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  
>06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"   
>*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.  
>*Action:

sql developer 18.2.0
DB = Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: you have sqldev 18.2, but which version of the DB (both local & remote)? Have a look at the doc, e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adlob/distributed-LOBs.html#GUID-7E450E86-3E4E-4714-A164-FD36B93722F6) on how to use remote lob locators

Comment: its 12c, and its means from one remote to another remote DB, I can do it using string but not with lob.

Answer (score 0):

There are various restrictions when using distributed LOBs. One way around this is to operate on a local LOB global temporary table as follows:

- Create a `global temporary table`
- Load the row and manipulating the LOB in this GTT
- Use `insert@remote as select from gtt` to copy the data over

Which looks like:

```
create table t (
  c1 int, c2 clob
);

create global temporary table gtt as
  select * from t
  where  1 = 0;

declare
  v2 clob default ' ';
begin

  dbms_lob.append (
    v2,
    chr (10)
  );
  dbms_lob.append (
    v2,
    q'[DOCTYPE]'
  );

  insert into gtt (
    c1, c2 
  ) values (
    1, v2
  );

  insert into t@loopback 
    select * from gtt;

end;
/

select * from t;

C1   C2          
    1  
DOCTYPE
```

*Loopback is a database link pointing back to the same database to simulate a remote DB*.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has the same problem he should run the dblink command through sys user
For example connect to database using system as sysdba.